# getting started with Openssl for certificates

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, openssh, pki

I am creating a simulation for Public key infrastructure in .NET.
I searched over google and found openssl for issuing certificated and revoking stuff etc.
I don't want to issue certificates for real-time use ,but It will be a simulation only.
Anybody who can guide me on what are the necessary functions that would help us in doing this.

Comment: You need to know how to use openssl or how to make something like openssl ?

Comment: @Arun I want to know how to use openssl for public key certificates?

Answer (score 0):

The commands are very simple and can be obtained easily by a simple google search .. The certificate structure and the directory structure for the entire process is kept in the openssl.conf file .

Edit the file as per your requirement . If u need to get an idea about PKI infrastructure on the whole ..wikipedia is a good place to start .. anyways just try this link

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

CA key:

openssl genrsa -out private/redkey.pem 1024

Create CA certificate:

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key private/redkey.pem -out redcacert.pem -config openssl.cnf  -set_serial 0x01

User certificate:

Key:

openssl genrsa -out OCSP/blueuserkey.pem 1024

Certificate request:

openssl req -new -key OCSP/blueuserkey.pem -out OCSP/blueuserreq.pem -config openssl.cnf

Certificate Creation:

openssl x509 -req -in OCSP/blueuserreq.pem -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions usr_cert -CA bluecacert.pem -CAkey  private/bluekey.pem -CAcreateserial -out OCSP/blueusercert.pem

Revoke a certificate:

openssl ca -revoke OCSP/blueusercert.pem -keyfile private/bluekey.pem -cert bluecacert.pem

GENERATING CRL:

openssl ca -gencrl -out blue.crl  -keyfile private/bluekey.pem -cert bluecacert.pem -crldays 2

Comment: Thank you, I checked the commands earlier but the thing is that even if you create a private key it will be created in a file.. how i will use this in my .NET app?is there any jar file available?

Comment: see the keys are generated in a file which is base 64 encoded [pem format] .. after decoding it you get the actual private key which is used to digitally sign the data .. am sorry i don't know much about .Net apps

Comment: My code will involve high filehandling , opening and closing of files in this way..